# Js variable into php call

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Im trying to move Js variable into php   , simply put var i instead of const 4

```
                            var  ntime = '<?php echo count($czasAr);?>';
                            for (var i = 0; i < ntime; i++) {
                                alert('<?php echo $czasAr["4"];?>');        
                            };
```

I have tried

```
<script>document.write(i)</script>
```

but it didn't work, alert was empty. any ideas?

Comment: That will never work. You are defining *ntime* as a string and attempting to for a for loop with it. for(var i=0; i < "50"; i++)

Comment: thanks, that arr = <?php echo json_encode($czasAr); ?>; worked :)

Comment: @user3370412: I wrote a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't move a **client-side** language variable to a **server-side** language like PHP directly for security reasons. That would be the end of the internet as we know it.

What you can do is for example do a GET request to the same page that contains a PHP script which will get the variable from the request. For example

JS part:

```
var yourVariable = "lorem";
document.location = "/theSamePage.php?variable=" + yourVariable;
```

PHP part:

```
$passedVariable = $_GET['variable'];
echo $passedVariable;
```

Or you can do a form for example which will handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate over a PHP array in JS. You might be better off injecting the whole array into JS and then iterate over it:

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($czasAr); ?>;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

The PHP and JS code usually run on *different* computers, you cannot simply mix those languages. PHP is executed on the server side, *generating* HTML and JS code, and JS is executed on the client in the browser. Read up on the [client-server model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model).